# Given that $\{a_n\}$ converges to $A$ how does this inequality $|a_n| < A +1 $ follows?

Tags: real-analysis

I have to understand this step in a proof in my textbook to understand the whole proof. But I not understand how this inequality: $|a_n| < |A|+1$, follows from the fact that $\{ a_n \}$ converges to $A$.

Kind regards

EDIT! Answer

Oh, I think I got it.

Be the reverse triangle inequality

$|a_n|-|A| ≤|a_n-A| < \epsilon = 1$ !!
Right :)?

Comment: It's not true for ALL $n$, for example $a_n = A + \frac{10}{n}$.

Comment: I do not understand this comment? It shouln't be true for all $n$? Only for $n \geq N$?

Comment: That's right. In your question you did not mention any $N$. Furthermore, if you wanted to express your question in a mathematically rigorous manner, it would be important to put in the correct quantifiers in.

Comment: Alright. Sorry, I'm still not comfortable with writing precious mathematically. But my idea is right?

Answer (score 1):

You want to bound $|a_n|:$

$|a_n| =$

$|(a_n-A)+A| \le |a_n-A| +|A|.$

Let $\epsilon =1;$

There is a $n_0$ s.t. for $n \ge n_0$

$|a_n-A|<1$.

Almost done.

Comment: Have I not done the same? Is this not the same idea?

Comment: As said in my earlier comment, you did not do exactly the same. This answer expresses $n_0$, and it expresses the exact quantifiers needed to make a TRUE statement. You did not express any $n_0$, and you did not express any quantifiers.

Comment: Lee Mosher Thanks:)

Comment: Xenusi. Hope Lee's comments clarified.